# casting Rc<Self> of trait T to Rc<T> in rust

Tags: rust, casting, traits

I have a trait which can be called `T`. In a lot of places i currently use `Rc<dyn T>`.
The problem is that i wanted to add a default method to `T` that runs a function the needs `Rc<dyn T>`. But as far as i can see there is no way to cast `Rc<Self>` because Self is not sized in a trait. I can not make the whole project use generics, so how could i get around this?
example:

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;
trait T {
    fn run_test_method(self: Rc<Self>) {
        test_method(self);
    }
}

struct A;
impl T for A {}

fn test_method(_rc: Rc<dyn T>) {
    // do stuff with 'rc'
}
fn main() {
    let a = Rc::new(A) as Rc<dyn T>;
    a.run_test_method();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler gives you multiple hints about this, and if you follow them all you will wind up with something like this, which does compile:

```
trait T {
    fn run_test_method(self: Rc<Self>)
    where
        Self: Sized + 'static,
    {
        test_method(self);
    }
}
```

The `Sized` bound is required so that the cast can be performed, and the `'static` bound is required because there is no lifetime on `dyn T` in the `test_method` argument, which makes it implicitly `dyn T + 'static`.

If you can't require the `'static` lifetime for some reason (because the implementors of `T` contain non-static borrows) then you can remove the `'static` bound on `T::run_test_method` if you indicate that the `dyn T` can have a non-static lifetime on `test_method`:

```
fn test_method(_rc: Rc<dyn T + '_>) {
    // do stuff with 'rc'
}
```

---

If you want to be able to call this method with *either* an `Rc<A>` or an `Rc<dyn T>` then you will have to implement this separately for both cases, because fundamentally each method does something different.  One casts a (pointer to a) sized value to a trait object, and the other does not.

You can accomplish this by using a helper trait that you implement for both cases.  (The type names here will be a bit confusing to people who work in Rust regularly because `T` is usually a generic type, but here it's a trait.)

```
// Remove the method from this type.
trait T {}

trait RunTestMethod {
    fn run_test_method(self);
}

impl<X: T> RunTestMethod for Rc<X> {
    fn run_test_method(self) {
        test_method(self);
    }
}

impl RunTestMethod for Rc<dyn T + '_> {
    fn run_test_method(self) {
        test_method(self);
    }
}
```

Note the compiler allows these implementations because they don't overlap.  Generic types are implicitly `Sized` unless otherwise specified, and `dyn T` is `!Sized` -- therefore the compiler can easily prove that the sets of types that each implementation will cover are disjoint.

Now, you can do this:

```
fn main() {
    let a = Rc::new(A);
    Rc::clone(&a).run_test_method();
    
    let b: Rc<dyn T> = a;
    b.run_test_method();
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d4f73ec33a9fdacc67f92cb22ad8ac98))

Comment: I will edit my question but the method run_test_method needs to be callable from `Rc<dyn T>`

Comment: @jk_games I've updated my answer to add a section explaining how you can achieve this in Rust. Ultimately, it's all kind of a hack, and it's likely that you should consider redesigning your trait, though I can't easily tell you how without knowing what it does and how it interacts with the rest of the system.